# How to pass AWK output into variable?

Tags: linux, awk, paragraph

I have a small bash script that greps/awk paragraph by using a keyword.

But after adding in the extra codes : `set var = "(......)"` it only prints a blank line and not the paragraph.

So I would like to ask if anyone knows how to properly pass the awk output into a variable for outputting?

My codes:

```
#!/bin/sh

set var = "(awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n";FS=OFS="\n"}/FileHeader/' /root/Desktop
/logs/Default.log)"
echo $var;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Make it a habit to always put double quotes around variables: `echo "$var"`.  This typically bites users with filenames containing spaces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) to capture the output of a process.

```
#!/bin/sh

VAR="$(awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n";FS=OFS="\n"}/FileHeader/' /root/Desktop/logs/Default.log)"
echo "$VAR"
```

some general advice with regards to shell scripting:

- (almost) always quote every variable reference.
- never put spaces around the equals sign in variable assignment.

Comment: @JavaNoob, you have to be carefull with backslashes inside the backticks. see here http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Answer (score 3):

- You need to use "command substitution". Place the command inside either backticks, `` `COMMAND` `` or, in a pair of parentheses preceded by a dollar sign, `$(COMMAND)`.
- To set a variable you don't use `set` and you can't have spaces before and after the `=`.

Try this:

```
var=$(awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n";FS=OFS="\n"}/FileHeader/' /root/Desktop/logs/Default.log)
echo $var
```

Answer (score 2):

You gave me the idea of this for killing a process :). Just chromium to whatever process you wanna kill.

Try this:

```
VAR=$(ps -ef | grep -i chromium | awk '{print $2}'); kill -9 $VAR 2>/dev/null; unset VAR;
```

Comment: You generally want to use the `ps -C` argument, as in `ps -C chromium`.  Using grep with ps output like this will eventually come back to bite you when there's a filename open in vim or something which matches the command you were grepping for.  And you can specify that just the pid be in the output, saving awk by using `ps -C chromium -o pid=`.

Comment: Or just use `killall chromium`, I guess ;)

Answer (score 1):

anytime you see grep piped to awk, you can drop the grep. for the above,

```
awk '/^password/ {print $2}'
```

awk can easily replace any text command like cut, tail, wc, tr etc. and especally multiple greps piped next to each other. i.e

```
grep some_co.mand | a | grep b ... to | awk '/a|b|and so on/ {some action}.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a variable coming from vault/Hashicorp, when using packer template variables, like so:

```
BUILD_PASSWORD=$(vault read secret/buildAccount| grep ^password | awk '{print $2}')
echo $BUILD_PASSWORD
```

You can to the same with `grep ^user`